# Promise getting resolved for undefined values

Tags: javascript, web, es6-promise

I am learning promises in Javascript and when I used Promise.all method for undefined values, "then" block is executing. Can anyone please help me in this regard to print the catch block for undefined values?

```
let promise1, promise2, promise3, totalPromises;

totalPromises = () => {
    return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
        .then(() => console.log("All promises are resolved"))
        .catch(() => console.log("All promises are not resolved"))
}

totalPromises();
```

Output:
All promises are resolved

Comment: That's because the catch block is triggered by a promise rejection, not an undefined value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the array passed to `Promise.all` has values which are not Promise objects (or thenables), then they are wrapped into promises, much like you would get with `Promise.resolve(value)`. If you don't want this behaviour for specific values, then you must write code to embed your desired behaviour.

For instance, the below `toPromise` function will return a *rejected* promise object when its argument is `undefined` and will wrap any other non-promise value into a Promise object using `Promise.resolve`.

You can map the array through that function before passing it to `Promise.all`:

```js
function toPromise(arg) {
    return arg === undefined      ? Promise.reject("value is undefined") 
         : arg instanceof Promise ? arg
                                  : Promise.resolve(arg) ;
}

let promise1, promise2, promise3, totalPromises;

totalPromises = () => {
    return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3].map(toPromise))
        .then(() => console.log("All promises are resolved"))
        .catch(() => console.log("Not all promises are resolved"))
}

totalPromises();
```

Now, maybe you want to extend this behaviour for when a value is `null` or some other undesired value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behaviour of `Promise.all`  and It's already defined in the documentation of the [Promise.all Fulfillment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#fulfillment)

> If a nonempty iterable is passed, and all of the promises fulfill, or are not promises, then the promise returned by this method is fulfilled asynchronously.